# Simplification of multiplication expressions with variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you simplify the expression $8v + 12v$  you get $20v$, Right? So if you have to simplify the expression $8v \times 12v$ would you do the same thing and get $20v$, or  would you get something like $20^v$. Also, what is the explanation behind this rule?

Comment: Multliplication is commutative and associative.  Associative means that it doesn't mater if we move the braces around. $(ab)(c) = (a)(bc)$ Commutative means we can change the order. That is  $ab = ba.$  Then $(18v)(12v) = (18\cdot 12)(v\cdot v)$

Comment: To add to Doug M's comment:  And distribution (combining addition and multiplication in the same expression) is $a(b + c) = ab + ac$.  So $8v + 12v = (8+12)v = 20v$.  That's why simplification works.  If we have $8v \cdot 12v$ it equals $8\cdot v\cdot 12\cdot v$ and we rearrange them.  Without addition it is a different expression and a different result.  There is no addition in it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to factoring and the rule that multiplication distributes over addition:

$a\times (b + c) = (a\times c) + (a\times c)$.

Bearing in mind that if we write two terms together such as $8v$ we mean $8\times v$.

So $8v + 12v =$

$(8\times v) + (12\times v) = $

$(8+ 12)\times v = $

$20\times v =$

$20v$.

If we don't have a $+$ then we don't use that rule.

$8v \times 12 v =$

$(8\times v) \times (12 \times v)$.

Well, instead we have the cummutative rule of multiplication:

$a \times b = b \times a$ (order doesn't matter)

And associativity rule of multiplication:

$(a \times b) \times c = a \times (b\times c)$ (it doesnt matter how you group them if they are all being multiplied.)

So:

$8v \times 12 v = $

$(8\times v)\times (12 \times v)=$

$8 \times v \times 12 \times v = $

$8 \times 12 \times v \times v = $

$(8\times 12) \times (v \times v) =$

$96 \times v^2 = $

$96v^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I think it helps to look at it from the perspective of factoring

$ 8v + 12v $

$= v(8 + 12) $

$= v(20) $

$= 20v$

In the case of the second one, remember that:

$8v$ is equivalent to $8 \times v$

Therefore, you can write the second statement as:

$8  \times  v  \times  12  \times  v$

Since multiplication is commutative and associative we can look at this as:

$(8 \times 12)  \times  (v \times v)$

$= 96  \times  v^2$

$=96v^2$

Answer (score 1):

No. $$8v\times 12 v=8\times v\times 12\times v=8\times12\times v\times v=96\times v^2=96v^2$$ due to associativity and commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: so when you simplify 8v×12v you get 96v2 ? also, why the down vote?

Comment: Yes. Downvote? Nobody's downvoted anything, neither your post nor my answer.

Comment: It was deleted right after I commented

Comment: That was not me. Coincidences...

Comment: I didn't downnvote it.  But I think this wouldn't help a novice who is truly having a conception barrier.  ... it comes across simple as "no, we don't do something that looks basically the same, it the same way; we do something entirely different-- for reasons that are completely arbitrary but totally different."